# Create a view to list all contents that uses media through any entity reference field

Tags: views, 8, entities

I know it is possible to create view to list all content that is using media through a **particular** entity reference field.

Is it possible to create a view to to list all content that is using media thought **any** entity reference field?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes, by [adding relationships to a view](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-relationship-to-a-view). The drawback is that is not done automatically: you manually have to add all entities/fields that possibly can refenrence a media entity. Create a view showing media entities. Then add the related tables and filter criterias *"related/foreign field referencing media -- is not empty"*

I'd not recommend the *"File usage"* relation and its *"Use count"* field. It doesn't seem to count correctly in my projects.